# connecting brocade ICX 7250 to Opendaylight controller Oxygen karaf-based

Tags: opendaylight

I have installed ODL Oxygen karaf-based and want to connect brocade switch of the series ICX 7250-24. the problem is that the odl does not establishe connection with the controller.
Please any one can help?

thanks!
Nadir

Answer (score 0):

do you have any meaningful messages in the ODL karaf.log? Check the switch logs
as well.

Comment: actually the switch is not getting connected. We are connecting to the ODL via switch ethernet interface 1/1/1/. It is necessary that 1/1/1 interface should not have IP address assigned in order to enable openflow on the interface 1/1/1. But neither pings nor it gets connected to the ODL.

Comment: you need your switch to connect to ODL via management network. if you don't have an ip address on the interface connecting directly to ODL, there is no way for it to connect.

Comment: then how would it be possible to connect other interfaces of the switch to ODL?

Comment: you only need one connection between a switch and the controller.

Comment: now I assigned the IP and the pinging is done. However, now I am getting the following error when I connect to the ODL controller running on IP 192.168.2.25 port 8181, the ethernet interface 1/1/1 of the ICX router 7250 (having IP 192.68.2.26 on virtual interface with VLAN10) is connected with the ODL controller,

Comment: and the error isand the error is on ICX 7250
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CS7250(config)#openflow controller ip-address 192.168.2.25 no-ssl port 8181

CS7250(config)#ERROR: Ctrl-1 in ver 4 sends pkt with hdr: ver 72 type 84 len 21584 xid 791752241
Bad Controller - teardown all connections!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: on the server it is 
=========================================
$sudo netstat -an | grep 8181

tcp6   0   0  :::8181     :::*   LISTEN

tcp6   0   0  192.168.2.25:8181     192.168.2.26:7801   TIME_WAIT

=================================================

Please what is wrong?
Thanks!
Nadir

Comment: port 8181 is not for openflow. try 6653 or 6633.  Also, make sure you have the right features installed on ODL.

Comment: hum, I think the port is not an error, How to make it sure that right features are installed on ODL

Comment: you pasted this "openflow controller ip-address 192.168.2.25 no-ssl port 8181". Port 8181 is for restconf. Openflow uses port 6653 and/or 6633. Here's a simple guide for checking features: https://docs.opendaylight.org/en/latest/getting-started-guide/installing_opendaylight.html